# How do I use route and have same directory name as route in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I have files in the following structure

```
index.php
help.php
help\helpone.php
help\helptwo.php
```

If I visit something.com, I'm taken to the correct index page with the .php removed from the end. When I goto something.com/help, nginx throws a 403. This is happening because there is a help folder inside the same directory. The requirement is to visit something.com/help to see the help page

help page has links to the other pages, so on click it becomes something.com/help/helpone

I have the following server block that does the operation.

```
server {
        root /usr/share/nginx/landing;
        server_name sample.com;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
            try_files  $uri/ $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
}
```

How can I achive sample.com/help without getting 403

Comment: `try_files  $uri/` explicitly says to return the directory if it exists. Remove `$uri/` if you don't want to serve directories.

Comment: You need to use `$uri` instead of `$uri/`

Comment: if `$uri/` is removed something.com doesn't work and have to goto `something.com/index.php` which is not desired. `$uri` leads to `no input file specified`

Comment: Add another `location = /` to handle http://something.com requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this issue was to move the `help.php` which was in the root directory to `help\index.php` This way Nginx will directly look inside folder `help` for index.php instead of conflicting between the `help.php` which was outside and the folder `help` doing a Forbidden Access.

Now going to `sample.com/help` goes directly into `sample.com/help/index.php` whithout showing you the `index.php` of-course.

Attaching nginx block for reference although nothing much changed.

```
index index.php index.html;

location / {
    try_files  $uri/ $uri.php;
}

location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
```

Folder structure

```
 index.php
 help\index.php
 help\help1.php
 help\help2.php
```

Output
`sample.com` goes to `sample.com/index.php` & doesn't show the `/index.php` so UX is also satisfied!

Answer (score 1):

That's because first it tries help/ directory, not help.php file. There is no index.php inside, so it shows 403 error.

Try:

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri.php$is_args$query_string $uri/;
    }
```

Or change the name of help.php file or directory.

Comment: This leads to 500 on the landing page and all the other pages if they are accessed without .php at the end. To access the landing page I have to manually goto sample.com/index.php which is not the required outcome. Also cannot have something.com/help. UX issue :(